# How to bring front character behind the panel in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAgyO.png)
How to bring front character behind the panel in unity.
you can see the image for more information.
i try to change sorting layer but it didn`t work.
please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAgyO.png)
..

Comment: theres 2 answers. Either a) Z needs to be nearer the camera, or b) thats what sorting layers are for